# Proving $n^2≤2^n+1$ for $n\geq 1$ by induction

Tags: induction

> Prove $n^2\leq 2^n+1$ for $n\geq 1$ using induction.

*Proof*. For $n=1, (1)^2\leq 2^1+1=3$. $\therefore 1\leq 3$ is true.

Assume $n=k$ is true so $k^2\leq 2^k+1$ or $k^2-1\leq 2^k$. Then prove for $n=k+1$.

Goal: $(k+1)^2\leq 2^{k+1}+1$

We have
$$
2^{k+1}+1=2\cdot 2^k+1\geq2\cdot(k^2-1)+1=2k^2-2+1=2k^2-1.
$$
I've got to the $2k^2-1$ but from there I'm stuck.  I can't see how I can show that the goal is true?  Or is that all I need to show for the proof?

Comment: I think you might find life easier if you check cases up to $n=3$ (or even $n=4$) and then run induction.

Comment: @Joffan Indeed, going up through $n=4$ is *just* what is needed :D (at least for a very natural proof by induction)

Answer (score 1):

Joffan's comment alludes to using *four* base cases (up through $n=4$), and I think this is the way to go:

For $n\geq 1$, let $S(n)$ denote the statement
$$
S(n) : n^2\leq 2^n+1.
$$

**Base step ($n=1,2,3,4$):** Showing that $S(1), S(2), S(3)$, and $S(4)$ all give true statements is easy, but the *reason* for going up through $n=4$ will become apparent below.

**Inductive step $S(k)\to S(k+1)$:** Fix some $k\geq 4$ and assume that 
$$
S(k) : k^2\leq 2^k+1
$$ 
holds. To be shown (i.e., the "goal" as you put it) is that
$$
S(k+1) : (k+1)^2\leq 2^{k+1}+1
$$
follows. Starting with the left-hand side of $S(k+1)$,
\begin{align}
(k+1)^2 &= k^2+2k+1\tag{expand}\\[0.5em]
&\leq (2^k+1)+2k+1\tag{by $S(k)$, the ind. hyp.}\\[0.5em]
&\leq (2^k+1)+2^k\tag{since $k\geq 4$; see $(\dagger)$}\\[0.5em]
&= 2\cdot 2^k+1\tag{group like terms}\\[0.5em]
&= 2^{k+1}+1\tag{by definition}
\end{align}
we end up at the right-hand side of $S(k+1)$, completing the inductive step.

By mathematical induction, the statement $S(n)$ is true for all $n\geq 1$. $\blacksquare$

---

**$(\dagger)$:** Why is it important to have $k\geq 4$ when we assert
$$
(2^k+1)+2k+1\leq (2^k+1)+2^k\quad?
$$
When simplified, this inequality clearly becomes
$$
2k+1\leq 2^k,
$$
but we need $k\geq 4$ for this inequality to be true in general ($k=1,2,3$ all cause problems, but everything is smooth sailing for $k=4$ and beyond, that is, when $k\geq 4$).

Answer (score 0):

You are left to prove:$$2k^2-1\ge(k+1)^2=k^2+2k+1$$This leads to proving:$$k^2\ge2(k+1)$$Which is true for $k\gt2$

Therefore you need to show the cases for $n=1$ and $n=2$ to be true and you are done.

Comment: But didn't i show in my original step that n=1 the steps are true?

Comment: Yes, therefore only case left to prove is $n=2$

Comment: okay i think i see than.  ugh.  I hate induction LMAO.  I gotta get this down so bee going over it all day.

Comment: Actually you have to check $n=3$ as well:  as noted, the inequality $k^2\ge2(k+1)$ only takes hold at $k=3$.  I.e., the inequality $2^2\lt 2^2+1$ does not help prove the *equality* $3^2=2^3+1$.

Comment: but aren't you when using induction proving for all numbers greater than say 1?  That's what the k is for I thought?

Comment: how are yall using the special characters lol

Comment: @NatashaEpperson See [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to properly typeset your mathematics.